# php ejecutar función cuando sea X fecha

Tags: php

tengo una función en php que me busca el usuario y contraseña en la base de datos mysql, y si lo encuentra (coinciden el usuario y contraseña) edita esa entrada y añade un token (numero aleatorio) y me devuelve para que lo lea en html un json con un mensaje de "ok" y el token.

Ahora lo que necesito es que ese número aleatorio cambie cuando pase X tiempo, por ejemplo 3 horas, (para hacer pruebas estoy con 3 segundos y tal)

He probado a utilizar dentro de la funcion del login, sleep(3) tras añadir el token y luego de esos 3 segundos buscar de nuevo el usuario y contraseña y poner un nuevo token, el problema, es que aunque funciona, no envia el echo json hasta que pasan los 3 segundos, es decir, ejecuto la función y a los 3 segundos envia los 2 echo json, el primero del primer login correcto con su token y el segundo con el nuevo token... y necesito que me lo envié antes del sleep.

He probado con while y me da el mismo resultado...

No pido ningún código solo algún consejo de como realizarlo, algún método o algo...

Gracias.

Comment: var bucle = setInterval(function(){tu_funcion(); },1000); el valor 1000 es igual a un segundo, prueba esta funcion

Comment: pero eso es para javascript, yo lo necesito en php...

Comment: Si necesitas una tarea que se ejecute periódicamente, no puedes depender de php u otro lenguaje cualquiera, ya que dependerás de que la aplicación se encuentre activa, y en el caso de php de que no exceda el tiempo de ejecución configurado en tu php.ini ``max_execution_time``, por lo cual la opción mas viable es crear un evento en el motor de base de datos que estés usando, estos evento son muy flexibles y lo mejor es que siempre están activos.

Comment: Debes intentar algo para que podamos ayudarte, un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). El evento que te propone @rpaillao tiene buena pinta... Si lo combinas con variables de sesión yo creo que podrías conseguir lo que buscas. Pero, en tu intento, es donde lo veremos con más claridad... :)

Comment: pues cuando lo consiga, si es que lo hago... lo pondré por aquí, pero por ahora tengo otras resoluciones mas prioritarias, gracias.

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: aqui tienes que mesclar 2 tecnologias: PHP y CronJobs y no tiene nada que ver con el tiempo limite de ejecucion.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque según el manual de Stack deberías ver el cómo preguntar (Deberías poner un ejemplo de código y evitar pedir consejo, solo deberías hacer preguntas específicas), te digo. Para hacer lo que quieres deberías crear una tarea cron en tu servidor. Esta tarea cron en tu servidor lo que hará es ejecutar un archivo PHP cada X tiempo que tu le definas. En este archivo es donde tienes que hacer la comprobación y actualizar el token de usuarios.